# tk2combobox: how to control response to up/down arrow keys

Tags: r, tk-toolkit

I've got a UI in R using tk2combobox.

If the control has focus, and I hit the "down-arrow" key, it expands the list, rather than changing the selection.
It doesn't actually change the selection until I arrow down and hit "enter" or click with the mouse.

Is there any way I can get it to change the selection immediately with the arrow key?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in Tcl.  I could not get the very first 
key-down to work, as somehow the interactions in bindings caused 
the second key-press to disappear.

```
package require Tk

proc ::lbarrowhandler { w } {
  set currselidx [$w curselection]
  regsub {\.popdown\.f\.l$} $w {} cb
  $cb current $currselidx
  return -code ok
}

set ::x cc
ttk::combobox .c -values {aa bb cc dd ee ff} -textvariable ::x
pack .c

bind ComboboxListbox <<ListboxSelect>> +[list ::lbarrowhandler %W]
```

**Edit:**

Another possibility is to use the ttk::spinbox with the -values option.
I don't know your exact use case, but this will give the user a limited
selection of values.  The disadvantage here is that the complete list 
is not visible.

```
set ::x cc
ttk::spinbox .sp -values {aa bb cc dd ee ff} -state readonly \
     -wrap true -textvariable ::x
pack .sp
```

The -state readonly prevent the user from typing anything in, and the
-wrap option will have the arrow controls wrap from end to beginning and
vice-versa.

References: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_spinbox.htm

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. But I'm still struggling. Your last line looked like the key. In R I said `tkbind(ct$Listbox, "<<ListboxSelected>>", cmd)` but nothing happened. Plain old "ct" didn't work either. Sigh.

Comment: Actually, 'ComboboxListbox' is a special class name known to Tk.   Leave that name as is and you should make progress.  Watch for typos.  Just '<<ListboxSelect>>', not '<<ListboxSelected>>'.

Comment: You mean like this? `tkbind(ct$ComboboxListbox, "<<ListboxSelect>>", cmd)` I haven't figured out where to find good doc on this.

Comment: Probably: tkbind("ComboboxListbox", "<<ListboxSelect>>", cmd)